# How are multiple dimens.xml files from multiple modules used?

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm a little bit confused how multiple `dimens.xml` files (not for different screen resolutions and sizes, but from multiple library modules) are handled in AndroidStudio.

I have an AndroidStudio project which consists of one main module (the runnable app) and several library modules, lets call them `module1` and `module2`.

From a xml file in my main module's layout folder I try to access a value stored in `dimens.xml` of `module2` like for example this `android:paddingBottom="@dimen/..."`, but I can only find dimens from `module1` and the main module itself.

My question is, how can I access the dimen values from the main module and all library modules? Why is it, that I get suggestions for the main modules' and `module1's` values but not for `module2`?

I'd appreciate any clarification on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android Gradle plugin and Android Studio recently made a change to support the concept of public and private resources in library projects.

This allows libraries to hide their resources from consuming applications, preventing polluting the resources namespace and preventing consumers from using resources that might change in future versions of the library.

By default, all resources in a library project are private.

To make a resource public, create a new `res/values/public.xml` resource file and put a definition in that file like so:

```
<resources>
    <public name="libraryname_dimen" type="dimen"/>
</resources>
```

This would make a dimension resource called `libraryname_dimen` public and thus available to other modules and/or consuming applications if you were to publish the AAR.

You can read more at the [Private Resources tools documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#PrivateResources).

Comment: I would also suggest to edit a bit more. on new documents, quoting:

>All resources in a library default to public. To make all resources implicitly private, you must define at least one specific attribute as public.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `android:paddingBottom="?attr/..."` to access such values.
This also works for colors.